# Prove if $f_n\rightarrow f$ in almost every point in E, then $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f_n:E\rightarrow\mathbb{\bar{R}}$, with $m(E)<\infty$. Prove if $f_n\rightarrow f$ in almost every point in E, then $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure.

**My attempt:**

Let $\epsilon, \delta >0$.

As $f_n\rightarrow f$ in almost every point then exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that  $m\{x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon\}=0$

As $\delta>0$ then $m\{x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon\}<\delta$ and this implies $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure by definition.

Is correct this?

Comment: Consider $E = (0, 1]$ and $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{nx}$. Then $f_n \to 0$ for *every* point $x \in E$, while $$m\{x\in E:|f_n(x)-0|>\epsilon\}=\frac{1}{\max\{1,n\epsilon\}} > 0.$$

Comment: IF you write a sentence with "there exists $N\in\Bbb N$ such that ..." and you never mention $N$ again, THEN it's most likely that it's not a mathematically meaningful sentence. Your $\delta$ sentence is just as bad.

Comment: If the theory of integration is available to you, I would strongly recommend Kavi Rama Murthy's answer to you. This is because it captures the essence of the problem, in the sense that the 'metric'
$$d(f, g) = \int_{E}\min\{1,|f-g|)\,\mathrm{d}m$$
yields the topology of convergence in measure on $E$, i.e., $f_n \to f$ in measure if and only if $d(f_n,f)\to0$. (Establishing this will comprise a good exercise as well.) And with aid of the convergence theorems (esp. DCT), this provides a very clear view on how a.e.-convergence implies convergence in measure.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is not correct as ponied out above.

One way of proving this is to use DCT. DCT is probably an overkill but it makes the proof very simple. If $f_n \to f$ a.e. in a finite measure space then $\int \min \{1,|f_n-f|\} d\mu \to 0$ . But $\min \{1,|f_n-f|\} >\epsilon$ whenever $|f_n-f| >\epsilon$  (and $0<\epsilon <1$) from which it follows that $\mu (|f_n-f| >\epsilon) \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Kavi Rama Murthy already gave a very elegant proof with aid of integral. So let me try to provide a less elegant but elementary proof. First, define

$$ Z_{n}(\epsilon) = \{ x \in E : |f_n(x) - x| \geq \epsilon \}. $$

Then for each $\epsilon > 0$, we easily find that

\begin{align*}
\{ x \in E : f_n(x) \not\to f(x) \}
&\supseteq \{x \in E : |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \epsilon \text{ for infinitely many $n$'s}\} \\
&= \cap_{N\geq 1}\cup_{n\geq N} Z_n(\epsilon).
\end{align*}

So the almost-everywhere convergence assumption asserts that $m\left( \cap_{N\geq 1}\cup_{n\geq N} Z_n(\epsilon) \right) = 0$. Then, since $E$ has finite measure and $N \mapsto \cup_{n\geq N} Z_n(\epsilon)$ is decreasing, we have

$$ \lim_{N\to\infty} m\left(\cup_{n\geq N} Z_n(\epsilon)\right) = 0. $$

Then from the inequality $ m(Z_N(\epsilon)) \leq m\left(\cup_{n\geq N} Z_n(\epsilon)\right) $, we find that $m(Z_N(\epsilon)) \to 0$ as $N\to\infty$. This implies the desired convergence in measure.